# Convert a KML file to an image file using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to convert a KML file with a lots of polygons into an image in order to put it into a PDF file with PHP. Is there any solution to achieve that ? I tried with Google Static Maps API but there are too much polygons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't involve PHP, but you could load the KML file into Google Earth Pro, and use the "Save image" tool (or just a screenshot) to export an image version of the map with the KML polygons.

If you don't want the map as the background, you can overlay a large filled polygon behind your KML polygons to give them a solid background color (white or otherwise).  May have to play with Draw Order settings in the KMLs to get them to overlay in the desired order.